# MySQL query for returning time sum over current results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, time, sum

So my query is like this:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('24:00:00',(TIMEDIFF('22:00:00',TIME(end)))) AS time
  FROM sworkingtime
 WHERE user='magdalena' 
       AND type='work' 
       AND start BETWEEN '2014-03-01' 
                     AND '2014-03-28' 
       AND (HOUR(`end`) > 22 OR HOUR(`end`) < 4)
       AND completed=1
```

My query returns this:

```
02:02:36
03:17:24
03:07:03
02:24:17
03:14:09
```

Is there a way to modify this query to return only SUM of this fields, so one field only?

Thank you

Comment: What is your original table structure & data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`TIME_TO_SEC()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) to convert the time intervals into a number of seconds, sum over that, and then use [`SEC_TO_TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) to express the result as a time value.

One can also rearrange the [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) expressions to simply add 2 hours onto each value of `end`:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(end)) + 2*60*60))
FROM   sworkingtime
WHERE  user = 'magdalena'
   AND type = 'work'
   AND start BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-28'
   AND (HOUR(end) > 22 OR HOUR(end) < 4)
   AND completed = 1
```

Comment: Works great, that's what I was missing. Thank you!